# Getting the voltage of an 18650 battery with an Arduino

Tags: power, analogread, voltage-level

I'm using a Arduino Pro Mini (5v) to sense the voltage of an 18650 battery. The battery (that is being sensed)is also used to power the Pro Mini but the MCU is behind a boost-converter which outputs 5.05v. Would I be able sense the right voltage of the battery?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9yFJI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The boost converter has an input voltage ranges to 0.9 to 5 volts and current of 600mA.

Comment: most cheap switch-modes are not isolated, so the ground is common. there's little/no reason to isolate unless there's inverted voltages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if Vin- and Vout- are joined together inside the boost converter or share a common ground on the boost converter circuit board such as this one:

[image]

[image]

Comment: My boost converter is different but the IN- and OUT- is connected.